# Logging Database Access Through ADO.NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

We have a legacy ASP.NET web application that executes many stored procedures via ADO.NET. Can anyone recommend a profiling tool or a straightforward method to log these database calls client-side when they occur?

I appreciate any tips.

Comment: you sure you want to log executed SQL commands _client-side_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4Net won't work if the app isn't already instrumented with it.

SQL Profiler is server-side and impacts sql server performance.

You should look at ADO.Net Trace Logging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964124(SQL.90).aspx

I believe it will do what you need to do.

Comment: Log4Net is very quick to setup.  I'm glad you've encouraged me to clarify that SQL Profiling isn't something that you leave running indefinitely.

Comment: Log4net is easy to set up. But you'll notice the O.P. said "legacy app". Probably unlikely to be making code changes to it to plug in log4net and instrument the codebase.

Answer (score 2):

Logging - [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

SQL Profiling - built-in [SQL Server Profiler](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3750161/Introduction-to-SQL-2005-Profiler-Part-1.htm)